# Populate new column based on associated values in data frame with shared column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames that I want to merge using rbind(), but first I need to add some columns that are missing in one of the data frames (DF1). This should be easy, as the data frames already share a column "id", so I hope to populate the new columns based on the values associated with "id" in DF2.

However, using the merge function does not work, as the columns that the data frames already have in common, are duplicated:

Create df1 and 2:

```
structure(list(id = c("a5", "b4", "c3", "d2"), tested = c(1, 
1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

structure(list(id = c("a5", "b4", "c3", "d2"), letter = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), tested = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

DF1 and 2, respectively

```
DF1
  id tested
1 a5      1
2 b4      1
3 c3      1
4 d2      1

DF2
  id letter tested
1 a5      a      0
2 b4      b      0
3 c3      c      0
4 d2      d      0
```

expected output:

```
1 a5      a      1
2 b4      b      1
3 c3      c      1
4 d2      d      1
```

so I can then rbind the new data frame, with df2.

EDIT: I have used @langtang solution which works for my sample dataset, but it does not for my own dataframes, as the merge function creates many duplicate rows for some reason. Please see below what I'm doing:

Create papoints3 and dfmerge3

```
structure(list(lon = c("550993.784327698", "338593.784327698", 
"556993.784327698", "556693.784327698", "208393.784327698", "151093.784327698", 
"-80506.2156723024", "134293.784327698", "-53506.2156723024", 
"180193.784327698"), lat = c("5229526.25410983", "5197726.25410983", 
"4955626.25410983", "5015626.25410983", "5144026.25410983", "4923226.25410983", 
"4833226.25410983", "5066026.25410983", "5062126.25410983", "5160526.25410983"
), id = c("10_18", "10_17", "10_17", "10_17", "10_17", "10_17", 
"10_17", "10_17", "10_17", "10_17"), presence = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(id = c("10_18", "10_17", "10_17", "10_17", "10_17", 
"10_17", "10_17", "10_17", "10_17", "10_17"), anim = c("10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10"), year = c("18", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17"), size = c(92.9234537616, 
92.9234537616, 92.9234537616, 92.9234537616, 92.9234537616, 92.9234537616, 
92.9234537616, 92.9234537616, 92.9234537616, 92.9234537616), 
    devpropmean = c(4.08349514563107, 4.08349514563107, 4.08349514563107, 
    4.08349514563107, 4.08349514563107, 4.08349514563107, 4.08349514563107, 
    4.08349514563107, 4.08349514563107, 4.08349514563107), agripropmean = c(7.90291262135922, 
    7.90291262135922, 7.90291262135922, 7.90291262135922, 7.90291262135922, 
    7.90291262135922, 7.90291262135922, 7.90291262135922, 7.90291262135922, 
    7.90291262135922), lon = c(382912.7413, 378828.6981, 387304.5394, 
    383399.8912, 376747.2341, 382911.7177, 382944.6976, 381972.7752, 
    382525.5573, 381937.5165), lat = c(5180174.902, 5179209.885, 
    5176330.37, 5179889.741, 5177147.879, 5180161.583, 5180207.628, 
    5179609.706, 5180023.505, 5179603.73), presence = c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
10L))
```

Then I do

```
papointsnew <- merge(papoints3,dfmerge3[,c("id","anim","year","size","devpropmean","agripropmean")],by="id")
```

but this returns 100 rows instead of the expected 10?
The output is 10 rows,
whereby each columns not merged with another data frame are kept as is (lon, lat, id, presence), but the others are now part of the data frame and values are given based on the shared column ID (year, size, devpropmean,...)

Comment: The problem you are having is that `id` is duplicated in both data sets so you are doing a many-to-many merge which is why you are getting more more rows than you expect. What is your expected output?

Comment: added a note about expected output @LMc , see also the answer below for what i'm after

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the letter column into df1, and then row-bind:

```
rbind(merge(df1,df2[,c("id", "letter")], by="id"), df2)
```

Output:

```
  id tested letter
1 a5      1      a
2 b4      1      b
3 c3      1      c
4 d2      1      d
5 a5      0      a
6 b4      0      b
7 c3      0      c
8 d2      0      d
```

Update to address the specific merge problem described in the OP's edit: if all you want are the constants in `anim`, `year`, `size`, `devpropmean`, and `agripropmean`, then try wrapping `dfmerge3` in `unique()`, as below:

```
rbind(
  merge(papoints3,unique(dfmerge3[,c("id","anim","year","size","devpropmean","agripropmean")]),by="id", all.x = T),
  dfmerge3
)
```

Output:

```
      id               lon              lat presence anim year     size devpropmean agripropmean
1  10_17  338593.784327698 5197726.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
2  10_17  556993.784327698 4955626.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
3  10_17  556693.784327698 5015626.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
4  10_17  208393.784327698 5144026.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
5  10_17  151093.784327698 4923226.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
6  10_17 -80506.2156723024 4833226.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
7  10_17  134293.784327698 5066026.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
8  10_17 -53506.2156723024 5062126.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
9  10_17  180193.784327698 5160526.25410983        0   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
10 10_18  550993.784327698 5229526.25410983        0   10   18 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
11 10_18       382912.7413      5180174.902        1   10   18 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
12 10_17       378828.6981      5179209.885        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
13 10_17       387304.5394       5176330.37        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
14 10_17       383399.8912      5179889.741        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
15 10_17       376747.2341      5177147.879        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
16 10_17       382911.7177      5180161.583        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
17 10_17       382944.6976      5180207.628        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
18 10_17       381972.7752      5179609.706        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
19 10_17       382525.5573      5180023.505        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
20 10_17       381937.5165       5179603.73        1   10   17 92.92345    4.083495     7.902913
```

Comment: Thank you, updated my question to reflect a problem i run into with this approach

Comment: just wrap your `df3merge[]` subset in `unique()` - see update